# Sorting Dictionary items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to print out the dictionary items that are sorted in alphabetical order of the 'Keys' but i want to sort the 'Items' according to increasing/decreasing order of the numerical values of 'Dictionary Values'

Note: The result must contain item tuples of the form (key, Values) and the sorted order should be according to increasing/decreasing order of numerical 'Values'

```
def calculate(sentence):
sentence = sentence.lower()
d = {}
for characters in sentence:
    d[characters] = d.get(characters, 0) + 1
return sorted(d.items())


print(calculate("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
```

How can this be done? Please help me with this and if the solution is complex try explaining it as simple as possible. I'm only a beginner

For example:
input = 'zzzzoopq'
output = [('z', 4), ('o', 2), ('p', 1), ('q', 1)]
(The output is sorted according to descending order of 'values')

Comment: add example of your sentence, and desired output

Comment: ```collection.Counter``` could replace your entire function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [defaultdicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) and [key/reverse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) arguments of sorted function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def calculate(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for ch in sentence:
        d[ch] += 1
    return sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

calculate("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

> ```
> [(' ', 8),
>  ('o', 4),
>  ('e', 3),
>  ('r', 2),
>  ('u', 2),
>  ('t', 2),
>  ('h', 2),
>  ('k', 1),
>  ('l', 1),
>  ('b', 1),
>  ('q', 1),
>  ('y', 1),
>  ('w', 1),
>  ('s', 1),
>  ('v', 1),
>  ('f', 1),
>  ('p', 1),
>  ('a', 1),
>  ('j', 1),
>  ('m', 1),
>  ('i', 1),
>  ('c', 1),
>  ('z', 1),
>  ('d', 1),
>  ('x', 1),
>  ('g', 1),
>  ('n', 1)]
> ```

Comment: Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of `defaultdict(int)` would clean up the `calculate` function quite a bit.